# PHP Regular Expression: String starts with and ends with

Tags: php, regex, expression

```
$ptn = "/^Response.+?[:] /";
$str = "Response from Moore Auto: Thanks for your feedback";
$rpltxt = "";
echo preg_replace($ptn, $rpltxt, $str);
```

"Moore Auto" is a variable name, so I simply need the text after the colon and space.  Desired final result would be the string "Thanks for your feedback" in this case. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple with `substr()` , like this:

```
$str = 'Response from Moore Auto: Thanks for your feedback';
echo substr($str, strpos($str,':')+2);  //echoes "Thanks for your feedback"
```

Comment: + for not using Regular Expressions when they're not the right tool.

Answer (score 0):

Damiens solution does not work, if there is more than one colon. This should always work if the first part doesn't contain a colon:

```
<?php 
$ptn = "/^Response[^:]+:\s*(.*)$/";
$str = "Response from Moore Auto: Thanks for your feedback";
if (preg_match($ptn, $str, $match)) {
    $text = $match[1];
    echo $text; //Thanks for your feedback
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<?php 
$ptn = "/^(Response.+[:])(.*?)/";
$str = "Response from Moore Auto: Thanks for your feedback";
$rpltxt = "$2";
echo preg_replace($ptn, $rpltxt, $str);
?>
```